# Implementation of hygienic macros

Tags: scheme

I am curious about the implementation of scheme macros as defined in r7rs. A lot is vague or hard to understand.

First I wonder - is the macro expander invoked before any code is compiled, so the compiler doesn't get to see any keywords? Or is the expander called on the fly while compiling?

Second, the docs say with hygiene and referential transparency, the expander needs the make bindings work in the spirit of lexical scoping. But knowing about these bindings means the expander needs to understand that `lambda` and `define` exist, or so I understand it. This contradicts the idea that the compiler and expander need to be separate, with the expander having no knowledge of existing keywords.

I would be grateful for any clarification.

Answer (score 3):

My answers are drawn from Racket, but I believe that what I'm going to tell you is applicable to R7RS. Apologies in advance if I'm mistaken.

1) The macro expansion phase is generally considered to be part of the compiler. EDIT:... but this is largely a matter of terminology. A better answer might be to say that expansion happens after the "read" phase in which character sequences are parsed into s-expression trees, but before the remaining stages of compilation.

2) You are *absolutely right* that hygiene requires a priori knowledge of binding forms, and where (for each binding form) the newly bound names occur, and where the new names are in scope. Keep in mind that it's fine for other forms to expand into binding forms, hygiene is generally implemented in a way that handles this just fine.

Answer (score 1):

These are good questions. I've been thinking about the same things for years and what I came up with was that the compiler needs to know the scope and workings of lambda at compile time. This isn't hard.

Another thing is that each macro expansion that introduces bindings that are not from the pattern or the macros lexical scope should be replaced by something unique. This ensures that recursive expansions doesn't interfer with each others identifiers.

If you look at DrRackets expansion you'll see that while the names are the same they color code the identifiers and hovering over them shows which one comes from which expansion. This is just the same as renaming, only with extra data not polluting the look of the names.

A good video of the hottest in compilers "these days" must be the [2013 nanopass talk by Andy Keep](https://youtu.be/Os7FE3J-U5Q). If you look the the code produced at the first step at `34:27` it does rename identifiers so there are no duplicates. The code is [available online](https://github.com/akeep/scheme-to-c) and I guess it lacks macros :-)

Answer (score 0):

Alright... https://www.scheme.com/tspl4/syntax.html claims the expansion phase is before and separate from compilation, but I always thought this is duplication of effort, keeping track of scopes, I thought an expert can't be wrong, I'm missing something.

So if I can be convinced transforming on the fly is better, I'll do that.

Other things...

With renaming, if the expander produces a `lambda`, are the arguments and references to the arguments always renamed (since they are not considered part of the lexical environment of the macro specification at that point)? I think I'll append with %000A or something ugly like that, incrementing every time.

Looks like syntax-rules's also need knowledge of `define`. If there is a top level define, and a syntax expansion that produces a reference to it needs to know if it exists in top-level scope. If the define occurs after the macro transfomer defintion, am I right to say this is a syntax error?

Are any other special properties of Scheme language necessary to know about, or just `lambda` and `define` (I can't figure out a way to get rid of `define`).

Comment: Had another thought, internal definitions can be converted to lambdas with magic in the compiler to optimize them away. So looks like all I need to worry about are `lambda` and top level `define`s.

Comment: converting internal defines may not always be straightforward in the presence of interior macro definitions etc. etc.. This is an active area of research. If you're looking for a reference, take a look at the current state-of-the-art, at http://www.cs.utah.edu/plt/scope-sets/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [video](https://youtu.be/Or_yKiI3Ha4) which goes into some detail about how it can be done.  The rough idea is that tag each identifier with the lexical scopes it was inside before you started expanding your macro and then you use that to decide which binding a use of an identifier should use.  There is a bit more but the video explains it way better than I could.